# Call to undefined function str_contains() php

Tags: php, function, compiler-errors

My code works on localhost via APACHE, but when I hosted a website with all the same files and code i get this message:
**Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function str_contains() in **/storage/ssd3/524/16325524/public_html/static/header.php** on line **55**
PHP Code where error shows:

```
<?php
$menu = getAllData('meni');
global $korisnik;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($menu); $i++){
    if(isset($_SESSION['korisnik'])){
        if(str_contains($menu[$i]->naziv, 'login') || str_contains($menu[$i]->naziv, 'reg')){
            continue;
        }
        echo  '<li><a href='.$menu[$i]->putanja.'>'.$menu[$i]->naziv.'</a></li>';
    }
    else {
        if (str_contains($menu[$i]->naziv, 'profile') || str_contains($menu[$i]->naziv, 'out')) {
            continue;
        }
        echo '<li><a href=' . $menu[$i]->putanja . '>' . $menu[$i]->naziv . '</a></li>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan—Although I don't see how the [original issue](https://github.com/kristijanhusak/laravel-form-builder/issues/556) is relevant here, please link to that instead of that spammy site.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

[str_contains()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php) was introduced in PHP 8 and is not supported in lower versions.

For lower PHP versions, you can use a workaround with [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
  // haystack contains needle
}
```

Answer (score 46):

The [manual page for str_contains](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php) says the function was introduced in PHP 8. I suspect your host is on PHP 7 (or possibly lower).

You can define a polyfill for earlier versions (adapted from https://github.com/symfony/polyfill-php80)

```
if (!function_exists('str_contains')) {
    function str_contains(string $haystack, string $needle): bool
    {
        return '' === $needle || false !== strpos($haystack, $needle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

[The docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php#:%7E:text=PHP%208) say `str_contains` was introduced in PHP 8.0.

Answer (score 4):

I tested [rjdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66519260/5116710) answer and it worked, but I added a way to return false in case some of the arguments are not strings:

```php
if (!function_exists('str_contains')) {
    function str_contains($haystack, $needle): bool {
        if ( is_string($haystack) && is_string($needle) ) {
            return '' === $needle || false !== strpos($haystack, $needle);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of silently returning false this code should implement type hinting which is already available in the language

Answer (score 1):

See enabled Apache modules

```
sudo apachectl -M
```

Disable 7.4 modules

```
sudo a2dismod php7.*
```

Enable php8

```
sudo a2enmod php8.1
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this code:

```
if (!function_exists('str_contains')) {
    function str_contains($haystack, $needle): bool {
        if ( is_string($haystack) && is_string($needle) ) {
            return '' === $needle || false !== strpos($haystack, $needle);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).